# add and disable submit button until user chooses answers for drop down questions

Tags: javascript, field, innerhtml

I am trying to add a button to a web page that will be disabled until the user selects answers from from a drop down menu for each question.  I have tried multiple approaches and end up with a submit button that's always active, always disabled or only works when extra elements like form tags are added to the page.  However, I can not change anything on the existing page, except add a button and java script that looks at the existing field on the page.

[Picture of existing HTML markup that can not be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhAV4.png)

`

```
$("#va11").keyup(function(event) {
    validateInputs();
});

$("#va12").keyup(function(event) {
    validateInputs();
});

$("#va13").keyup(function(event) {
    validateInputs();
});

function validateInputs(){
    var disableButton = false;

    var val1 = $("#cf_Q1").val();
    var val2 = $("#cf_Q2").val();
    var val3 = $("#cf_Q2").val();

    if(val1.length == 0 || val2.length == 0 || val3.length == 0)
        disableButton = true;

    $('#contact').attr('disabled', disableButton);
}
```

`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. Not an image of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>      

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label><br>
                <!-- Dropdown menu-->           
                <select id="cf_Q2" name="xvptags">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option trigger="Terminate" value="1: Under 18">1: Under 18</option>
                    <option value="2: 18-24">2: 18-24</option>
                    <option value="3: 25-34">3: 25-34</option>
                    <option value="4: 35-44">4: 35-44</option>
                    <option value="5: 45-54">5: 45-54</option>
                    <option value="6: 55-64">6: 55-64</option>
                    <option value="7: Older than 65">7: Older than 65</option>
                </select>
            </label><br>

            <!-- Disabled button -->
            <button type="button" id="button1" disabled>Click Me!</button>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Something will be done when user clicks on "question1"-element
            document.getElementById("cf_Q2").addEventListener("change", function() {
                //Did user choose a valid option?
                if(this.selectedIndex > 0) {
                    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = false;
                }

                //No element is chosen anymore - button should be disabled again
                else {
                    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to enable the button only when all questions are answered, you can use the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>      
        </head>
        <body> 
            <span style="font-size:16px;">Q1:&nbsp;</span>
            <span style="font-size:18px;">
                Are you over the age of 18?
            </span>
            <span style="font-size:18px;"> </span>

            <!-- Dropdown menu-->
            <select id="cf_Q1" name="xvptags">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1: Yes">1: Yes</option>
                <option value="2: No">2: No</option>
            </select>

            <br><br>

            <span style="font-size:16px;">Q2:&nbsp;</span>
            <span style="font-size:18px;">
                For statistical purposes, please tell me which category your current age falls into?
            </span>
            <span style="font-size:18px;"> </span><br>

            <!-- Dropdown menu-->
            <select id="cf_Q2" name="xvptags">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1: Under 18"></option>
                <option value="2: 18-24">2: 18-24</option>
                <option value="3: 25-34">3: 25-34</option>
                <option value="4: 35-44">4: 35-44</option>
                <option value="5: 45-54">5: 45-54</option>
                <option value="6: 55-64">6: 55-64</option>
                <option value="7: Older than 65">7: Older than 65</option>
                <br>
            </select>

            <br><br>

            <span style="font-size:16px;">Q3:&nbsp;</span>
            <span style="font-size:18px;">What is your gender?</span>

            <!-- Dropdown menu-->
            <select id="cf_Q3" name="xvptags">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1: Male">1: Male</option>
                <option value="2: Female">2: Female</option>
            </select>

            <br><br><br>

            <!-- Disabled button -->
            <button type="button" id="button1" disabled>Click Me!</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
                    
                    //Creates an array of length arr.length filled with -1
                    var array = Array(arr.length).fill(-1);

                    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        arr[i].addEventListener("change", function() {

                            //This should now also work with e.g. cf_Q12
                            var x = parseInt(this.id.substring(4)) - 1;
                            array[x] = this.selectedIndex;

                            var bool = false;
                            for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                                if(array[j] < 1) {
                                    bool = true;
                                }
                            }
                            document.getElementById("button1").disabled = bool;
                        });
                    }
                </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That might work.  I have multiple existing inner-html fields in the existing page that are pre-named and can not be changed (cf_Q1, cf_Q2, cf_Q3), and can not be wrapped in form tags. So i would need multiple EventListeners, or ways to check the fields.

Comment: @MarkWiant I just edited my answer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I attempted to use the second script with my existing page, and button does not become active after selecting answers from my 3 pre-existing drop down menus.  So I am really not sure what is causing it to hang, but it works like a charm with your 3 questions. There is a picture of my pre-existing HTML in my original post.

Comment: @MarkWiant Just updated the second snippet. Does this work for you?

Comment: It does work, to a degree, the button becomes active after selecting the last option on my three questions, but if I go back up and remove the selection from any of of the fields and make the field blank again the button still stays active, when it should be going back to inactive, because the field this blank again.

Comment: @MarkWiant Just updated the second snippet again. The button now gets disabled again when I unselect (CTRL + click) again.

Comment: I have added what I am using here and I guess it's waiting for approval, I get and Uncaught SyntaxError here for my code  and the button never returns to inactive for me when I implement on my page.

Comment: Actually, I does work on my page.  The button, however does no go back to inactive when the fields are cleared.

Comment: @MarkWiant Just updated the code again so it works here also. If this answers your question, I would appreciate if you accept this answer (click on the checkmark besides this answer). This also helps the community, because other people will see that this question is already answered.

Comment: I see, thanks for you continued help and patience!! This is a little outside of my expertise level.

Comment: I see and understand what you did on "Answer 1" above with the single drop down. How do the tie that script to the other 19 questions in my survey?

Comment: @MarkWiant You can do it like in the second snippet. Create an array of all the elements with `document.getElementsByTagName('select')` and add an EventListener to all the elements in the array.

Comment: Okay, so I done as you instructed, and all was well until question 10 and it stops working... I can create a survey with 9 questions and it works like a charm... then when I add question 10 and add it to the array it stops working.

Comment: @MarkWiant I just updated the second snippet. I have made two changes and added a comment where the changes are. Does this work for you now?

Comment: Yes, that worked like a charm!! I was going at it from a totally different direction.  Thanks again!!

Comment: I have another quick question.  As I am trying to understand this fully.  Is there another method I can use other that " var array = Array(arr.length).fill(-1);"  (specifically .fill)?

Comment: @MarkWiant You can also create a new array and use the push-function arr.length-times. But that's not an equally good alternative. I highly recommend to use `Array(arr.length).fill(-1)`.

Comment: Okay, I am not at all familiar with "push-function arr.length-times".

Comment: @MarkWiant If you have to create an array that contains 10 times the element "-1", then you can create a new empty array and use the push-function (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) ten times to fill the array.